# How do I change the Copyright information on a rendered file before rendering?

Tags: video

I was looking at one of my render outputs (from blender render) and when I looked in more info (on OSX), I saw something that caught my eye.

[image]

How do I make it so that I can change that text in Blender before rendering? I'm using Quicktime with H.264 output but was wondering if I could do this with other video output types. I'm assuming python is required.

Comment: You can always render it out as a PNG sequence then bring it into another program to render it out as a QT file.

Comment: @icYou But my question is to do it inside blender. I know that I can do that outside but it kinda dilutes the challenge, and won't work for my situation, which is to distribute a blend file publicly that will have my copyright info in it which would be transferred into any exported media.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the [Blender source code](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/quicktime/apple/qtkit_export.m), the copyright seems to be hard-coded with the line:

> [qtexport->movie setAttribute:@"Made with Blender"

For this reason I don't think the copyright message is configurable via the interface nor via Blender's Python API, meaning the only option is to edit the copyright manually after rendering or see if you can write a Python script to do this (which would be a question for [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081444/changing-a-files-metadata-in-python)) and get it to execute automatically after rendering with an [`app.handler`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77a_release/bpy.app.handlers.html?highlight=render_post).

Comment: So I cannot like "inject" this into the blend file. Is there any other way to inject metadata into a blend file only for it to pass onto the rendered output?

Comment: Not as far as I am aware. Anything like that would be done with the Python API, but I can't find anything that would allow that.

Comment: Well this is intended to add an author attribute to the blend file along with anything exported from it. How about the metadata function under the render tab where it says notes. Would that be transferred onto the movie file? I know it works for individual jpeg and png image files.

Comment: Yes, it would be transferred onto the file, but you may need other tools to be able to read back that metadata as opposed to seeing it in the window in your screenshot. See: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48700/find-blender-png-or-other-format-metadata-in-adobe

Comment: For the image outputs, I can see the metadata straightaway by opening it in a text application and looking at the compiled mess. No problem. My real issue is if the metadata option applies to video outputs because I tried looking it up in the compiled mess of the mov file and found nothing.